# Shiny for Python: Clearing Local Files on Session Close

Tags: python-3.x, py-shiny

## How Do I Delete Local Files on Session Close?

My app allows users to upload a file and request some server-side stuff be done to it. Awesome. However, I don't want these files to stay there. [Looking at the documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/api/reference/shiny.Session.on_ended.html), something like this should work (sanitized to protect the innocent)...

```
from shiny import App, reactive, render, ui
import os

def server(input, output, session):
     def delete_uploaded_file():
        try:
            os.remove('file.xlsx')))
        except:
            # If there isn't a file, it's not really a problem
            pass

    # This triggers at the end of a session
    session.on_ended(delete_uploaded_file())

    # this closes the session when the user exits out on their browser
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.close)
    async def _():
        await session.close()

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

but it yields an 'Exception in ASGI application' and a 'TypeError,' all without triggering any of the above code. Everything in the traceback seems to point to shiny, so what am I doing wrong here?

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\websockets\websockets_impl.py", line 238, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "C:\Users\e365627\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\_app.py", line 220, in __call__
    await self.starlette_app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 149, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\_autoreload.py", line 114, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 341, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 82, in app
    await func(session)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\_app.py", line 294, in _on_connect_cb
    await session._run()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\session\_session.py", line 326, in _run
    self._run_session_end_tasks()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\session\_session.py", line 228, in _run_session_end_tasks
    self._on_ended_callbacks.invoke()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiny\_utils.py", line 335, in invoke
    fn()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
INFO:     connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
from shiny import App, reactive, render, ui
import os

def server(input, output, session):
     def delete_uploaded_file():
        try:
            os.remove('file.xlsx')))
        except:
            # If there isn't a file, it's not really a problem
            pass


    # this closes the session when the user exits out on their browser
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.close)
    async def _():
        delete_uploaded_file()
        await session.close()

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

So your fuction is executed before the session is closed

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis after the function name:

session.on_ended(delete_uploaded_file())

should be

session.on_ended(delete_uploaded_file)